# Link website and Facebook Page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have website with like button and facebook page that was created manually. I want link these pages. So when user clicks like button, he subscribes on facebook page and he will recieve all updates in the future. How can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would depend on if the like button is "liking" your Facebook page, or your website URL.

If it's liking your Facebook page, then the user is automatically subscribed to all those updates - just like if the user had clicked "like" on Facebook.

If it's liking your website URL then you can't make them automatically like the facebook page too.

Comment: When I use my FB Page url for like button, it appears on wall like one line of text, without image and etc. If I use my website url - I don't see any Admin page link, but it appears on wall with image and description.

Comment: Thats just how Facebook works. Can't really do anything about that.
You can't force Facebook to like two things at once (i.e. your facebook page and your website), so you have a choice, either get people to like your facebook page and subscribe to the content you post on there, or get them to like your website and get nothing out of it apart from the larger initial post on their wall.

Answer (score 2):

I think, when you put like button of you FB page its linked automatically.